# Enabling experimental features in Docker Desktop hangs indefinitely on M1

Tags: apple-silicon, docker

When I try to enable (check the checkbox, then click the "Apply & Restart") the following experimental features

1. Use the new Virtualization Framework
2. Enable VirtioFS accelerated directory sharing

in *Docker Desktop / Preferences / Experimental Features*, the process hangs indefinitely. I let it run for ~3h in the background, to see if this is just very slow.

Here's how it looks like:

[image: indefinite-loader]

System details:

- OS: macOS Monterey 12.6 (21G115)
- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)
- Chip Apple M1 Pro
- Memory 16 GB
- Startup Disk Macintosh HD

The question is, how do I enable these experimental features?

Is it possible to do so either via editing some configuration files in */Applications/Docker.app/Contents/*, or via the `docker` command itself?

Has anyone experienced a similar issue and managed to solve it?

Related [Github's docker/for-mac issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6492)

Comment: It is experimental so expect it to fail and report the bug to the authors

Comment: I did (see the "Related" link attached). Still, there's a chance someone else has figured it out.

Comment: Isn't that just a better writeip of an existing issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6487 - definitely I would stick to Github or if a paid up user contact Docker directly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that before posting my own